# design a method returning a value or changing some data but not both

Tags: design-patterns

I vaguely remember reading somewhere a while ago that either a method/function should return a value without modifying the state or should process some data changing a state but not returning data. It is beyond simple getters and setters.

I cannot figure where I read that, the rationale and if this was a sound principle. It may be simpler to test for sure but is there any other reason? Is there is there a related design principle or pattern? Any clue or link appreciated.

Thanks
Olivier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That principle is called **Command–query separation**.

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation):

> Command–query separation (CQS) is a principle of imperative computer programming. It was devised by Bertrand Meyer as part of his pioneering work on the Eiffel programming language.
>
> It states that every method should either be a *command* that performs an action, or a *query* that returns data to the caller, but not both. In other words, *Asking a question should not change the answer*. More formally, methods should return a value only if they are referentially transparent and hence possess no side effects.

Personally, I think this principle is very helpful. It is based on a common observation that: when we see a function that returns some data, we *tend to think* that it does not change any state of data. In other words, that function does not have any side-effect. In constrast, functions with side-effects are considered "risky" and therefore should have a clear indication (returning `void` type). You see, C# has the concept of *Properties* where you change state of a property by using the assignment symbol which is a stronger indication than setter methods.

To conclude, the CQS principle helps our code to be easier to read and reason since managing how state changes is crucial in programming.

You can find more useful links in the wikipedia article, and [this](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2016/05/06/cqs-and-server-generated-entity-ids/) and [this](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/08/11/cqs-versus-server-generated-ids/).

Comment: Good answer. I'd argue that trying to apply this principle to all of your code would make it far more tedious to write and maintain, however. For instance: straight-forward methods like Queue.Dequeue(); would need to be broken into two commands: one to remove the next item from the queue (data structure modification) and one to retrieve the result.

Comment: You might be interesting in how Functional Programming handles your case: returning both the element and new queue/stack: https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/stack-based-calculator/ (section `Popping the stack`).

Comment: Functional Programming is fun, though I've had limited opportunity to use full-on functional programming out in the field. You could certainly adhere to the pattern by creating a new stack like that - though then I'd question why you would want to take the performance hit of creating another stack every time you push/pop just to adhere to the pattern? Nice idea though :)

Comment: You could improve it, however, by defining the stack as a single entry value and a pointer to another stack. So a linked-list stack. Then pop() would be the same as just returning the next node in the linked list, and push() would create a new node that points to the older head node. Then at least you aren't re-creating the entire stack every time. But how to keep all references to the stack the same while still adhering to the pattern? Hmmm

Comment: If you read the F# implementation in the link, you will see that it does exactly what you proposed. Anw, in general, if you find a particular part in your program is curical with performance, then implement it with mutability style if it can boost the performance. We should not be dogmatic with immutabilty or any principle, but rather find a trade-off depending on our situation.

Comment: "But how to keep all references to the stack the same while still adhering to the pattern? " That's an interesting and big topic which cannot be discussed in comments, you can ask another question tagged with `function-programming`.

Comment: created a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53237990/how-to-keep-immutable-stack-references-in-sync