# CQS Design Principle Problem: Implementing a Queue

Tags: design-patterns, functional-programming

I'm creating this question based upon a small discussion I had in the comments to the answer to this question: [design a method returning a value or changing some data but not both](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53235806/design-a-method-returning-a-value-or-changing-some-data-but-not-both/53237628?noredirect=1#comment93361796_53237628)

@Kata pointed out that the pattern that the OP was interested in is called **Command–query separation** and argued that this is a good model to structure your code by.

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation):

> Command–query separation (CQS) is a principle of imperative computer programming. It was devised by Bertrand Meyer as part of his pioneering work on the Eiffel programming language.
>
> It states that every method should either be a command that performs an action, or a query that returns data to the caller, but not both. In other words, Asking a question should not change the answer.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation) More formally, methods should return a value only if they are referentially transparent and hence possess no side effects.

I questioned the soundness of this design principle, as in general it would appear to make your code far more tedious. For instance: you could not perform a simple statement like **next = Queue.Dequeue();** You would need two instructions: one to modify the data structure and one to read the result.

@Kata found an alternative Stack implementation that at first glance appears to satisfy the best of both worlds: taking a page from functional programming, we define our Stack as an immutable data-structure. Whenever we push(x) we create a new Stack node that holds the value x and maintains a pointer to the old head Stack instance. Whenever we pop() we just return the pointer to the next Stack instance. Thus we can adhere to the Command-Query Separation Principle.

Example Stack Implementation: https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/stack-based-calculator/

However, one thing that is unclear in this case is how you would keep multiple references to the Stack in sync while still adhering to the Command-Query Separation Principle? I don't see an obvious solution to this. So as a point of curiosity I'm posing this problem to the community to see if we can't find a satisfactory solution :)

EDIT: Here is an example of the problem:

```
s = new Stack();
s2 = s
...
s = s.push(x);
assert(s == s2); // this will fail
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Functional Programming (FP) style, we often design our functions so that we don't need to keep such those references in sync.

Consider this scenario: you create a stack `s`, inject it into a `Client` object, then push an item to `s` and get a new stack `s2`:

```
s = new Stack()
client = new Client(s)
s2 = s.push(...)
```

Because `s` and `s2` are not in sync (i.e., they are different stacks), inside the object `client`, it still sees the old version of stack (`s`) which is something you don't want. Here is the code of `Client`:

```
class Client {
    private Stack stack;
    // other properties
    public Client(Stack stack) { this.stack = stack; }
    public SomeType foo(/*some parameters*/) {
        // access this.stack
    }
}
```

To solve this, the functional approach does not use such an implicit reference, but instead passes the reference into the function as an explicit parameter:

```
class Client {
    // some properties
    public SomeType foo(Stack stack, /*some parameters*/) {
        // access stack
    }
}
```

Of course, sometimes this would be painful as the function now has one extra parameter. Every caller of `Client` must maintain a stack in order to call the `foo` function. That's why in FP you tend to see functions with more parameters than in OOP.

But FP has a concept which can mitigate this pain: the so-called [partial application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application). If you already have a stack `s`, you can write `client.foo(s)` to get an "upgraded" version of `foo` which does not require a stack but only requires the other `some parameters`. Then you can pass that upgraded `foo` function to a receiver who does not maintain any stack.

Nevertheless, it's worth to mention that there are people who agure that this pain can be actually helpful. For example, Scott Wlaschin in his article [Functional approaches to dependency injection](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/dependency-injection-1/):

> The downside of course, is that there are now five extra parameters for the function, which looks painful. (Of course, the equivalent method in the OO version also had these five dependencies, but they were implicit).
>
> In my opinion though, this pain is actually helpful! With OO style interfaces, there is a natural tendency for them to accrete crud over time. But with explicit parameters like this, there is a natural disincentive to have too many dependencies! The need for a guideline such as the Interface Segregation Principle is much diminished.

Also, Mark Seemann -- the author of the book [Dependency Injection](https://www.manning.com/books/dependency-injection-second-edition-principles-practices-patterns) -- had an interesting series on [Dependency Rejection](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2017/01/27/from-dependency-injection-to-dependency-rejection/).

In case you cannot suffer that pain, then just break the CQS and back to the traditional implementation of Stack. After all, if a function (like `pop`/`dequeue`) is well-known and well-aware that it both returns something and changes its internal data, a violation of CQS is not so bad.

Even in this case, some FP languages offer a message-passing mechanism so that you can implement a mutable Stack in a manner that you don't write code mutating data (e.g., code using assignment symbol). [MailboxProcessor](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/concurrency-actor-model/) in F# is such a mechanism.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I do need to make more use of partial applications; very powerful :) I still don't think CQS makes much sense as a general design principle to follow, however, because of the unnecessary added complexity. It maybe better to argue that it is beneficial for particular scenarios rather than as a general design principle.

Comment: I would add that the wikipedia article uses _"should"_ rather than _"must"_, according to the usual specs terminology this means that is more a suggestion rather than a requirement/constraint. As a principle it makes sense, for not putting too many concerns all together in one function, and to give a shared mind framework for when to expect side-effects or not. Of course there will be situations where the application of this principle is not desirable or counterproductive (depending on the use case) and of course *it can* be skipped for something that makes contextually more sense.

Comment: But I am biased here: I tend to favor code that keeps concerns separated and that reduces the cognitive load :)

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the design of the function, you need to return a state which reflects the context.

This allows you to differentiate between success and  failure as well as potentially other information if you supplement bool with a DequeueResult in the following minimal party code.

Let Dequeue = function bool(Result)

If Head == Null return 
...
Return true

Something more inline with CQS might be

Let Dequeue = function Node()
Return Head

But would require Head to have a special value of Node.Null   to try my differentiate between failures and contention.

Returning a DequeueResult may be better where you can indicate in the result more about the failure.

Comment: This version of Dequeue does not return the element. You can work around this by peeking before dequeuing, but then you are right back to my original complaint about CQS: you have made your code far more tedious since you now require multiple operations to accomplish the same basic tasks that you could complete in one step by not following the CQS.

Comment: Then you want 
Let Dequeue = function Node()
Return Head you would have to have a special operator for Node or have a Node.Null

Comment: But then how do you solve the problem of keeping multiple stack references in sync? See example code in the OP.

Comment: You wouldn't be able to assign a Node to a Stack variable unless we are assuming JavaScript, in which case const is the solution